# Passing an ndarray into a function

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following function

```
def Rdot(t):
    if t < Tw_up:
        phase = (Tw_up - t)/Tw_up
    elif t < Tw_down:
        phase = 0
    elif t < Tw_end:
        phase = (Tw_down - t)/(Tw_down - Tw_end)
    else:
        phase = 1
    return (np.sin(t) + np.sin(t + phase*np.pi))
```

where `Tw_up`, `Tw_down` and `Tw_end` are `floats`.

I'm trying to get the value of `Rdot` for an `ndarray` of `ts`:

```
T = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
R = Rdot(T)
```

but I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\jonny\Desktop\PhD\projectCodes\python-firedrakeCodes\2benneyLukeNoBuoy\untitled0.py", line 18, in <module>
    R = Rdot(t)

  File "C:\Users\jonny\Desktop\PhD\projectCodes\python-firedrakeCodes\2benneyLukeNoBuoy\untitled0.py", line 7, in Rdot
    if t < Tw_up:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How might I get the method to work? I could of course create an arbitrary array and loop over the elements to populate with the correct values, but what I'm trying here is a lot more elegant.

Comment: the problem isn't with the function.  You can't use an array in an `if`.The error explains why.  "eligance' has nothing to do with this.  `if` is not an 'iterator'

Comment: Generally we try to avoid using `if/else` with arrays.  Instead we use tools like boolean masks, `np.where` and `np.select` to set values for the whole array, without python level iterations (that includes `map`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to apply a function to every instance

```
R = map(Rdot, T)
```

Comment: Oh thanks! How do I turn the `map` object into an `ndarray`?

Comment: Nvm, got it. `np.fromiter`